# PyDev only shows errors, warning, problems of opened files

Tags: eclipse, warnings, pydev

I have no idea why, but the problems window in Eclipse shows only errors and warnings, despite having checked "Show all" and "Show all items".

I would like to see all problems of my python project, without having to open 100+ files.

Comment: Does it let you "Build" the project? If so, did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected.

PyDev does not show the errors for all files, only for the currently opened file (the main reason this is so is to keep PyDev faster and using less memory so that it does not have to be constantly computing that information on the background).

Still, it's possible to force PyDev to perform the code analysis of several files at once (and seeing the result on the problems view) by **right-clicking a folder/project** and selecting **PyDev > Code Analysis** -- note that this will be a 'snapshot' of the current situation and PyDev will only update that information when you redo that operation or open a Python file.